# Remove or disable java due to the security issue

Tags: java, security

According to the news there's java security hole that is still not fixed. How can Ubuntu users protect their PC? I've got gnome-shell installed and as far as I understand it depends on java. Which packages should I remove?

There's a guide for Mac users at Mozilla's site, but not for Linux. [How to turn off Java applets](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/How%20to%20turn%20off%20Java%20applets?s=java&r=0&as=s)

Comment: Is Iced Tea affected?

Comment: I guess yes http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/08/critical-java-exploit-spreads/

Comment: use Noscript addon if you are using firefox, it is selective highly efficient javascript, java and others blocker

Answer (score 3):

**For Firefox**,
Open `Tools/Add-ons/Plugins` (Keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and find it on the list. Click the 'Disable' button to the right of it to disable the plugin. (Note that I've never bothered installing it so it's not present in my screenshot. If you have it installed you will see it here.)

[image: FF plugins]

**For Chrome,**
Go to `chrome://plugins/`. Find it in the list of plugins and click on 'Disable'. (Once again I am using Flash in my screenshot example because I never installed Java.)

[image: Chrome plugins dialog]

Note that the **Java plugin** and **Javascript** are two different things. See [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_javascript.xml) [Java.com] or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/245062) [stackoverflow.com] for an explanation of the differences.

Answer (score 0):

According [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) (installation guide) these packages are the ones related to java plugin for browsers:

```
icedtea6-plugin icedtea-7-plugin
```

Try remove them.

Answer (score -1):

Your browser should have the option to disable Java plugin.

**For Chrome:**

[image]

Under the Plug-ins section of the settings url: chrome://settings/content select "Block All".

With this option enabled, when you want to run plugins on a page you have 3 options:

1.Right click on the plugin and choose "Run this plug-in" from the context menu

2.Click the plugin icon in the URL bar and choose "Run all plug-ins this time

3.Add an exception for sites you trust so that they can run plugins without your explicit permission each time

[Source - Dan Herbert](https://superuser.com/questions/201613/disable-java-plugin-in-google-chrome)

**For Firefox**

By default, Firefox allows Java applets to launch automatically. However, you may decide that you do not want Java applets to run. To disable Java applets in Firefox:

1.At the top of the Firefox window, click on the Firefox button (Tools menu in Windows XP), and then click Add-ons. The Add-ons Manager tab will open.

2.In the Add-ons Manager tab, select the Plugins panel.

3.Click on the Java (TM) Platform plugin to select it.

4.Click on the Disable button (if the button says Enable, Java is already disabled).

[image]

Java applets will no longer be permitted to launch in Firefox.

[Source](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/How%20to%20turn%20off%20Java%20applets)
[Source 2](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/javascript-settings-for-interactive-web-pages)

**If you want to remove Java from your system, simply remove the packages you have installed.**

To search Java packages, in a console type

```
dpkg -l java
```

Comment: what about the dependencies? IMO gnome-shell is java-based.

Comment: though "The vulnerability has nothing to do with JavaScript."

Comment: When you first open the question you didn't specify the kind of vulnerability. Besides the article says: "Please, for the love of your computer, disable Java on your browser." And you should really read the article with attention and less paranoia. "So far, all of the exploits reported to be in the wild attack Windows PCs, but according to Errata Security CTO David Maynor, it's not hard exploit Mac and Linux machines that have the latest version of Java from Oracle installed. Neither platform has it installed by default, however."

Comment: I just have to recommend you reading any IT related media news as of today or yesterday keep the track of what's going on. The link I provided is just one among thousands. One more "The vulnerability affects all operating systems. In theory, a virus author could program malware that exploits the hole to infect Windows, Mac OS X and Linux computers. Only a few operating system-specific adjustments would need to be made." http://www.h-online.com/security/features/The-new-Java-0day-examined-1677789.html

Comment: You are talking of a highly hypothetical cenario. But if you're so concerned just remove java packages from your system.

Comment: Java is NOT JavaScript. -1