# Java 1.7 bugs affect ubuntu too?

Tags: java, security

I remember hearing bad things about java 1.7 on windows and OS-X, but are the same security holes present in Ubuntu?

Comment: You should be more specific on your question and cite your sources (ex: with links referring the specific security holes). This will help you to get an answer.

Comment: Chances are that if it has a multi-platform security hole then it'll affect Ubuntu as well.  However, without any specifics, it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181884/should-i-disable-the-iced-tea-plugin-for-now), it does affect ubuntu. Browser plugins should not be allowed to run unconditionally, but rather with a click. This will allow you to run only on those plugins which you trust.