# Is Java installed by default?

Tags: java, malware

I'm asking this because Libre Office was pre-installed and some of it's features require Java. I don't want Java because of a malicious remote administration tool (RAT) called [jRAT](http://jrat-project.org/) and there are also others. But with this even a script kiddie can take control of my computer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple answer, Java is not installed by default in any Ubuntu system (in fact this goes against the Java distribution policy, that's why is being included in the non-free repository).

You can check the packages manifest of any version of Ubuntu, and you will notice that it does not include either JDK nor Java.

Precise Pangolin package manifest:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.manifest

Raring Ringtail package manifest:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/raring/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.manifest

You can search the list up and down, and you will find no reference to Java (please don't confuse with JavaScript, that is different).

<sub>(Links are thanks [to our friend Oli](https://askubuntu.com/a/48894/169736))</sub>

- *How does LibreOffice run, then?*

  `libreoffice` suggest the package `java-runtime` for some specifics functions but isn't necessary the complete Java Virtual Machine. It also includes their very own packages with Java classes, scripts, and config snippets called `libreoffice-java-common`, but not all the suite require the packages (only writer and base). Hence, you can use most of LO without even installing Oracle's Java or openJDK.
- *Do you just mean Oracle Java is not installed? Is OpenJDK also not present?*

  This was answered above:

  > You can check the packages manifest of any version of Ubuntu, and you will notice that it does not include either JDK nor Java.

- *Are the differences between Oracle Java and OpenJDK from a security perspective are pretty small?*

  According to [Thomas Pornin from Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin), yes, the differences are none. Both share lots of code, which made them both vulnerable. There was even a [case where Ubuntu was affected by one vulnerability](https://askubuntu.com/a/181904/169736) which right now is fixed. <sub>(non citatory)</sub>

  You can read his full answer (along others) [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/27953/27973).

Hope this address all inquiries.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This is a very good answer! A couple points: right now it looks like the added quotes were the OP's words, so I recommend putting them in italics or making `###` headings out of them instead of using blockquotes. (I do not need credit for them, though--this is only about possible confusion regarding what the OP said.) Also, regarding `libreoffice-java-common`: I believe this is a (totally legitimate and positive!) instance of [a program shipping its own JRE](http://askubuntu.com/q/341118#comment435799_341118). Couldn't someone with access use it for other Java software?

Comment: @EliahKagan I think I should ask in security.se about that. But my hunch right now is that it isn't a java vm (the package is way too small), hence if you try to run arbitrary java code using that library, it will fail.

Comment: Just what I wanted to know. Thans!